# Why does oscilloscope still shows the signal even though its GND is not connected?

Tags: oscilloscope

if i connect oscilloscop's + probe to the components's plus side it still shows the signal. But how can this happen without connecting the GND ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases the o'scope ground is connected to the mains earth, and your circuit's ground too, so there is a ground connection.

If either ground is not thus connected there is still a relatively large capacitive coupling.

Comment: "If either ground is not thus connected there is still a relatively large capacitive coupling." what do you mean by that. is that the 2nd option?

Comment: if o'scope 's power supply socket is connected to a plug which has only line and neutral does that mean it is not connected to mains earth? i mean like this: https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Types-of-Power-Connectors-and-Plugs.jpg

Comment: Yes, that is the alternative (weaker) option. A consequence is that a DC signal will not show reliably, and with a modest load (take a 1k resistor) the signal should disappear. That is a plug for a non-earthed device - does your scope have that plug?

Comment: yes both has the circuit and scope has such plug. can it be mains earth is connected to neutral somewhere ?

Comment: A mains-powered device with a european style plug should never have a galvanic connection between any human-reachable part of the device and one of the two mains pins.

Comment: Are you positive it's that style of plug and not the very similar one with earth contacts ( https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CEE-7-7-Stecker.jpg )? I don't think i've ever seen a scope that didn't have an earth connection.